# How to filter eagerly loaded fields in SQLAlchemy queries?

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, orm, fastapi

I have a query to get a Company entity with nested User entities:

```py
async def get_company_by_id(self, company_id: int) -> Company:
        logger.debug(f "Received data:\n{get_args()}")

        query = (
            select(Company)
            .join(Company.users)
            .join(CompanyUser.users)
            .options(
                contains_eager(Company.users)
                .contains_eager(CompanyUser.users)
            )
            .where(Company.id == company_id)
        )
        result: Company = await self.get_instance(query)

        if result:
            logger.debug(f'Retrieved company by id "{company_id}":"{result}")
        return result
```

Pydantic-response looks like this:

```json
{
  "title": "string",
  "description": "string",
  "id": 0,
  "created_at": "2023-11-21T14:58:49.109Z",
  "owner_email": "user@example.com",
  "owner_phone": "string",
  "owner_name": "string",
  "users": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "name": "string",
      "email": "string",
      "phone_number": "string",
      "role": "owner"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to add functionality to filter users by phone number when getting a company. For example, if the phone number is "string" I will get a response like the above, if the phone number is different and none of the users' phone number matches it I want to get a response like this:

```json
{
  "title": "string",
  "description": "string",
  ...
  "users": []
}
```

That is, I need to filter only User entities. I tried to do it in the following way:

```py
async def get_company_by_id(self, company_id: int) -> Company:
       ...
        query = (
            select(Company)
            .join(Company.users)
            .join(CompanyUser.users)
            .options(
                contains_eager(Company.users)
                .contains_eager(CompanyUser.users)
            )
            .where(Company.id == company_id)
            .filter(User.phone_number.like("string"))

        )
        result: Company = await self.get_instance(query)
     ...
```

However, the problem is that since I am doing table joins, instead of a company with an empty list of users I get None returned, because the SQL query filters the entire row completely, including the company fields. How can I change the ORM query so that I can filter only the User entities?

Comment: use left join that will keep the company

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74075241/sqlalchemy-filter-children/74087962#74087962) using `execution_options(populate_existing=True)` in combination with `contains_eager`, I think that might be what you're after.

Comment: I still get None if none of the users matches the filter condition. Maybe something is wrong with the filter technique.

Answer (score 0):

To keekp the all companys even without  any users, you need a `LEFT JOIN`

in sqllachemy you add `isouter=True` to the join

```
        select(Company)
        .join(Company.users,isouter=True)
        .join(CompanyUser.users,isouter=True)
```

or

```
 select(Company) 
.outerjoin(Company.users) 
.outerjoin(CompanyUser.users)
```

Comment: The query still returns None. The same with the .outerjoin method

Comment: you also need a outer join around the second table also

Comment: I did it. The final query is:
 
query = (
            select(Company)
            .outerjoin(Company.users)
            .outerjoin(CompanyUser.users)
            .options(contains_eager(Company.users).contains_eager(CompanyUser.users))
            .where(Company.id == company_id)
            .filter(User.id == 321312)
        )

Comment: and did it work or not please don forget the mark the answer as accepted

Comment: Sorry. It didn't work: the response is still None

Comment: why have the where clause  in your query, that makes no sense remove it

Comment: Why do you think so? I retrieve a single Company by  its id

Comment: have you checked if the company_id actually exists

Comment: Yep, it is validated in the service layer

Comment: start by removing the options and the where clasue it should at least show one row with the phone number ysou submit, and then add the where clause and so on, one of them is responsible